# Get any information from Google Big Query

Tags: authentication, curl, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery

I need a bit help with BigQuery API, because I can't get or post any HTTP request with Auth problem.

I have found information about how to send http requests to GBQ on this links:

https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/?apix=true

More than that, I had an opportunity to get info about my dataset using built-in API. But can't find info about API_KEY and ACCESS_TOKEN.

I need an example of request or maybe links, where can i find/create my tokens. Client ID and Client secret are also created by me.

Here is cURL which works on Try This Method (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/get):

```
curl \
  'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/PROJECT/datasets/DATASET?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Owu.jpg)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: @DeltaGeorge, thank you. This link was very useful to find a token that i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using curl method instead in Linux/MacOS(I used Cloud shell) or Windows so that you can explicitly define your service key in the environment. For service account and keys creation, and also setting it into your environment you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup#creating_service_accounts_and_keys).

Command:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{my-projectId}/datasets/{my-datasetId}"
```

Output:

```
a@cloudshell:~ (a)$ curl -X GET \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{my-projectId}/datasets/{my-datasetId}"
{
  "kind": "bigquery#dataset",
  "etag": "Sg/LBN/riP3JmF+QDeKpLg==",
  "id": "{my-projectId}:{my-datasetId}",
  "selfLink": "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{my-projectId}/datasets/{my-datasetId}",
  "datasetReference": {
    "datasetId": "{my-datasetId}",
    "projectId": "{my-projectId}"
  },
  "access": [
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "specialGroup": "projectWriters"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "specialGroup": "projectOwners"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "userByEmail": "{my-email}"
    },
    {
      "role": "READER",
      "specialGroup": "projectReaders"
    }
  ],
  "creationTime": "1640656847727",
  "lastModifiedTime": "1640656847727",
  "location": "{my-location}",
  "type": "DEFAULT"
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It works for me. Starting with your code, i don't understand, where to get  "gcloud auth application-default print-access-token", but thanks to @DeltaGeorge, i understood where to go. More than that, i can now insert data into the table using POST method. Thanks again!